# Cassandra: How to partition data in multiple disks in single server?

Tags: cassandra-2.1

I want use cassandra in my server and the server has five disks, can i partition data across disks? in other words,How to store data in this disks with partition key? i read cassandra can partition in multiple servers, how to do same for multiple disks?
TNX

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Cassandra can make use of multiple disks.

In the cassandra.yaml file there is property called data_file_directories.  Under that you can give a list of data directories, so you would list one for each disk using paths appropriate for your OS for specifying different physical disks.

That's all you need to do and Cassandra will evenly distribute inserted data across the specified data directories.